# MySQL join 2 tables by ID

Tags: mysql, join

In my table "teams" I have unique IDs (player_1, player_2, player_3, player_4, player_5) of the players and in my table "players" those ID referer to the name of the players. For example in a search script case (search by name) :

```
The user write "foo" but "foo" is ID 20.

"teams" ID 1 => player_1 ID = 20
"players" player_id = 20 > name = foo
```

Here is my query :

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM teams LEFT JOIN players ON players.name LIKE :word';
```

But it didn't work as I wan't...

Comment: You need a conditional expression. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/join.html :) ... p.s. your LIKE expression looks wired as well (check http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-comparison-functions.html)

Comment: `ON` is supposed to be used to link the two table, you should give the columns used to join the table, `WHERE` condition is instead what you need whn you compare column against strings

Answer (score 0):

Try below query

```
select * from teams as tm,players as py where tm.player_1=py.player_id and py.name LIKE 'foo%'
```

Why you require join on teams table? you can use search by name only using players table.

Answer (score 0):

Join on id = player_id and search by name:

```
select * from teams join players on player_id = ID where name like 'Adam%';
+-----------+---------+----+---------+
| player_id | team_id | ID | name    |
+-----------+---------+----+---------+
|         1 |       1 |  1 | Adam G. |
|         3 |       2 |  3 | Adam S. |
+-----------+---------+----+---------+
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/14439/1)

if you use the same field name in both tables, you can join based on column:

```
select * from teams join players using (player_id) where name like '%S.';
+-----------+---------+---------+
| player_id | team_id | name    |
+-----------+---------+---------+
|         3 |       2 | Adam S. |
|         5 |       1 | Jim S.  |
+-----------+---------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/45f1e0/1)